# socket timeout in android app from jetty 9

Tags: android, servlets, jetty

My android app sends an HTTP request to a servlet on a Jetty Server and receives a response. It worked fine in Jetty 6.1.26. It also works fine in Jetty 7.6.13( which uses servlet-api-2.5.jar) and Jetty 8.1.15( which uses servlet-api-3.0.jar) But when i deploy the exact same servlet to Jetty 9.1.5.v20140505(which uses servlet-api-3.1.jar) on the same machine, it results in a socket timeout in my android app. I use java  jre1.7.0_55.

In the android app, the connection timeout is 3000 and socket timeout is 5000. Even if i increase the socket timeout to 30,000, it makes no difference. But if i set it to 40,000 it works.

Any idea what's going on? Why does the android code take so much time to accept the servlet response from jetty 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the response.setContentLength() in my servlet resolved the issue. I was sending about 30 characters as a response, but had set the length to 1024. My guess is that the Android app is expecting more data looking at the length set in the response, so it waits till some kind of timeout happens. Apparently, servlet 3.1 in Jetty 9 behaves differently from previous versions.